# Access images inside jar

Tags: java, jar, embedded-resource

First. I know that there already exists a variety of topics on how to access the image inside the jar file. 
Second. I tried many options and none of them did not work. Of course I know that somewhere I make a mistake. Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

so, I have prototype project with name 'j' and it contains just one java class - Client.
Client trying to access to image good.png. After I packed all to executable jar file, Client can't accesss file.
I work in eclipse, and use ant.

```
j/
-src/
--com/
---pupcom/
----Client.java
-images/
--good.png
-build.xml
-.classpath
-.project
```

com.pupcom.Client contains

```
package com.pupcom;
//imports;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String [] a) {
        new Client();
    }
    public Client() {
        URL imageURL =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images"+File.separator+"good.png");
        if(imageURL != null){
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
            if(image != null){
                System.out.println("Complete!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("image == null");
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("imageURL == null");
        }
    }
}
```

build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="j" basedir=".">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
    <property name="main-class" value="com.pupcom.Client"/>
    <property name="jar.name" value="j.jar"/>
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete file="${jar.name}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/images"/>
        <copy todir="${build.dir}/images">
            <fileset dir="images" />
        </copy>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
            <java  jar="${jar.name}" fork="true"/>
        </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <jar destfile="${jar.name}">
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

I also used these lines:

```
URL imageURL =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(File.separator + "images"+File.separator+"good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  getClass().getResource(File.separator + "images"+File.separator+"good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  getClass().getResource("good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  Client.class.getResource(File.separator + "images"+File.separator+"good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  Client.class.getResource("good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  Client.class.getClassLoader().getResource(File.separator + "images"+File.separator+"good.PNG");
URL imageURL =  Client.class.getClassLoader().getResource("good.PNG");
```

Thanks for any help!!!!!!!!!!

Thanks to Marko Topolnik, the problem was solved by replacing 'File.separator' to '/'.
Many thanks to Marko Topolnik!!!!

Comment: It is wrong to use `File.separator` in this context. If you run this on Windows, it will fail. URLs don't use platform-specific separators and the backslash is the wrong separator to use.

Comment: The structure of the Java project is actually not interesting. The structure you need to provide is the one of you jar file (`jar tvf thejarfile.jar`). Looks like there is a missing leading forward slash (but can't be sure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't use the `File.separator` in `getResource()` - it **always** takes `/` (think of it as an URL HREF).
2. Prefix the path with `/` to ensure the class loader searches from the root of the class-path, rather than relative to the package of the class.
3. Check that `good.PNG` is the correct case.  It does not matter on the Windows file-system, but `getResource()` is case-sensitive.

Comment: i made the mistake when wrote 'PNG', it also was a problem, but main problem was in 'File.separator', because i also really used 'png'. Thanks!